# How to get rid of a double breadcrumb in a view

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs

I have a User view, bringing in nodes via a relationship relating content that references the User in one of the node fields.  I have an attachment to the page, that pulls in content that references the user via another of the node fields.  I also have a block, and an attachment to the block, that pull in the same content.

The issue that I'm having, is that when viewing the page, the title of the view shows up twice in the breadcrumbs, once linked, and once not:

[image]

Other views on the site don't have this issue:

[image]

I've tried all kind of things, including exporting the view, grepping for all references to menu, deleting them, and reimporting the view to be sure the double breadcrumb wasn't the result of residual menu info from an experiment I made with having tabs in the page instead of an attachment.  I also cleared any references to the view from the menus on the site.  Of course I cleared cache after each of these attempts.  I can't figure out why it seems to think we are viewing a page called Missions to Approve (missions/to-approve) which is a child of page Missions to Approve (missions/to-approve).  Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to debug this from afar without having access to your site. But here are a few ideas worth looking into. See if there are view template files for these views or check to see if there is a preprocess function in template.php that affect these views or breadcrumbs

Comment: Thank you, I disabled the only custom view module I had just to be sure and that didn’t change anything. I also looked at my theme and the only thing I have in there related to views is overriding a couple of fields.